# Hyperlink in AlertDialog crashes with ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-alertdialog, intentfilter, activitynotfoundexception

I'm trying something simple. Include a hyperlink in an AlertDialog message. I can include the hyperlink and it is drawn as a hyperlink as desired. But when clicking on it, the app crashes:

**ActivityMain.java**

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        ad.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\\\"http://www.google.com\\\">Check this link out</a>));
        ad.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ad.show();
        TextView textView = (TextView) ad.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

In my **AndroidManifext.xml** I added the intend-filter *android.intent.action.VIEW*, but its still crashing.

```
        <activity
            android:name="org.app.test"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Logcat error message**

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=\"http://www.google.com\" (has extras) }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1672)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1442)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3511)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Native Method)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3472)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Native Method)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:748)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3714)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Native Method)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3682)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Native Method)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:323)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(Native Method)
            at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
            at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:217)
            at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:9180)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8107)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2280)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1615)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:757)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2228)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8315)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4596)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4464)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4022)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4076)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4045)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4156)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4053)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$Async
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a call to the users web browser to open it or a call to webview to open in app. You don't have anything coded to cover that.

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
webview.loadUrl(www.google.com);
```

The above is for in app.
For pulling the users web client:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
final Activiy activity = this;
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
   }
 });
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String  description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description,     
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
     });
    webview.loadUrl("www.google.com");
```

Comment: Ok, can you give an example please?

Comment: Which are you trying to do? That's a big thing. I'm assuming in app?

Comment: Yes, its an Android app. I just want to add the hyperlink to my AlertDialog so that its opening the URL on click in the smartphones default browser (most likely Chrome).  It shouldn't be a big thing... Just a small alert dialog. I dont want to create an own Activity for that or something bigger...

Comment: add import android.webkit.WebView at the beginning of your script, make sure to add permission for internet use as I did not see that in your script and you still have to make a call to a new webview. All of it goes in onCreate()

Comment: I want to avoid a webview because it creates a lot of overhead... Permission for internet is set of course `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`. I want to do it with AlertDialog. The link is already drawn, just want to get rid of that error...

Comment: I'm going to build it and post it for you when I'm done.

Comment: curious, are you testing with AVD or an actual device?

Comment: I'm testing with actual device... Thanks for your effort. I guess finally  I found a simple solution that works well now after hours of trying... :) See below...

Answer (score 0):

If I use Linkify, the link can be clicked without error and is opened in the webbrowser.

```
String msg = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Check this link out</a>";

final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(msg);
Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.ALL);

AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage(s)
                        .setTitle("Click a link in AlertDialog")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                        .create();

TextView textView = (TextView) ad.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

That's **ALMOST** what I want to achieve... But the link is not rendered correctly... :(

This is the result it prints into my AlertDialog:

< a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Check this link out< /a>

Of course it should show it without HTML tags, like this -> [Check this link out](http://www.google.com) ...

---

**So here is the final solution** to get well formated Hyperlinks inside AlertDialogs without any errors:

```
    String msg = "Check this link out, and I will send you to Google.";

    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Open a Hyperlink inside AlertDialog")
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .create();

    ad.show();

    TextView message = (TextView) ad.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    addLinks(message , "Check this link out", "http://www.google.com");
```

The only thing we need to do is add a small new function **addLinks(Textview, String, String)** to our class. Otherwise the generated URL will be wrong when we would use only Linkify.addLinks(TextView textView, Pattern pattern, String scheme).

```
public static void addLinks(TextView textView, String linkThis, String toThis)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(linkThis);
        String scheme = toThis;
        Linkify.addLinks(textView, pattern, scheme, new Linkify.MatchFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
                return true;
            }
        }, new Linkify.TransformFilter() {

            @Override
            public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
                return "";
            }
        });
    }
```

So, this makes it really comfortable! :)